# Intermittent wifi on Macbook Pro Mid 2010

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, macbook-pro

Experiencing connectivity issues on my Macbook Pro 2010... ping works flawlessly however every 2 minutes or so while browsing the internet (with both safari and chrome), I will run into a timeout and nothing loads for another minute, after which the cycle repeats. Any idea how to fix this issue?